# Scrabble Triple Word Score Question

Tags: scrabble, scoring

In Scrabble, If on the board there is:

PICKLE

If you start at the E tile, go down one tile, then right one tile there is a triple word score.

If you put SO vertically at the end of pickles (So the O would  be on the triple word score):

```
  PICKLES
        O
```

Does just SO get triple word score, or does PICKLES and SO both get their score tripled?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From the [official rules](http://www.hasbro.com/scrabble/en_US/discover/rules.cfm) on Hasbro's website:

> Premium Word Squares: The score for an entire word is doubled when one of its letters is placed on a pink square: it is tripled when one of its letters is placed on a red square.

The Triple Word square triples the value of any word played on it. So in your example, SO would score triple points, but PICKLES only scores normally. However, if the triple word square was directly to the right of PICKLE, then by placing the S on it you'd triple the score for both words.